# Do you know if in a C++ template method can one determine at compile type if a typename or typedef has been declared in a class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template method I want to do something like this:

```
template<typename>
void doSomething(T *arg) {
    if(typename_exists<T::TypeDeclaredInT>::value) {
        arg->doSomethingElse<T::TypeDeclaredInT>(arg);
    }
}
```

is there some std::is_type_declared<T::TypeDeclaredInT>::value
Or another way to accomplish this ?
??

Comment: there is something called a [type_info](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info), and another called a [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid),but i dont know if thats what you want

Comment: In C++20, just use `if constexpr(requires {typename T::TypeDeclaredInT;})`

Comment: @ShreeyashShrestha type_info is runtime only, c++17 has `if constexpr`